# Tab management code in single-page applications acceptable violations of the DRY principle?

Tags: angularjs, dry

I have an AngularJS-based single-page app that allows the user to operate multiple items at the same time. I decided to use a multi-tab UI implemented in custom code.

However, the user begin to ask for more and more tab management features like rearranging, going back to the last tab after closing, etc. and it feels like I am just duplicating tab management features of the browser.

Unfortunately, it is difficult to span one Angular application across mutliple tabs, so is this kind of reinventing the wheel acceptable?

(I tried to look for existing widgets with these features, but can't find one fits the bill perfectly.)

Comment: following a dogma when it doesn't apply to your environment leads to mindless fanaticism. DRY is a good principle, it is *not* a good master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplication of programming constructs is bad, but it's not as bad as failing to fulfil a requirement. If the sane way of providing functionality is to repeat blocks of code *and there is no way around it*, then the correct thing to do is to repeat them.

It can, however, be an indicator that you should ditch your coding environment for one that *does* have a way around it.